# Easy way to get parameters in Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, forms, servlets

I have a controller in a Spring application and I want to process an HTML form with it that changes the CSS. So I have the action of the form as "changeCSS" and the controller takes over from there. My question is: how do I actually get the values I submitted in the form? The resources I found online are all overly complicated and want me to create model objects I don't really need.

The values I'm looking for are called color1, color2, etc. and they should replace the hardcoded color values in the String.format() methods.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "changeCSS", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String changeCss() {

    BufferedWriter writer;
    try {
        String colorNewSettings3 = String.format(colorSettings.get("3"), "#000");
        String colorNewSettings4 = String.format(colorSettings.get("4"), "#fff");
        String path = context.getRealPath("/static/css/custom.css");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
        out.write(colorNewSettings3+colorNewSettings4);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //Use a Logger here
    }

    return "settings";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get form parameter is as shown in the below example. This requires you to create a Model object which in my opinion is not an overkill.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Now if you do not want to do that and stick to picking each values with a GET, the below snippet does that.

```
http://localhost:8080/changeCSS?color1=green&color2=red

@RequestMapping(value = "/changeCSS", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String changeCss(@RequestParam("color1") String color1, @RequestParam("color2") String color2) {


     ....

}
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping